# Suggestions to store an integer in an android app

Tags: android, server

I am new to android programming, i just need to store an integer on a server, so that my app can consult and update the value of that int. I listen useful suggestions of more experienced android developers whether if i need a server or there is a simpler solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just storing a local SharedPreferences setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose you want to store int on server .
If you want to store int within phone , you have different techniques for that

Comment: Because i want the users to see the updated value of that int. Storing it on the phone memory wouldnt work for my purposes.

Comment: for that purpose use php script to save that int to a database in server. By passing request to that php script from your phone , you can store the value in database